# Getting "Shared with Everyone" Folder Information in SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, onedrive, sharepoint-online

Does anyone have any idea how to go about getting "Shared with Everyone" information from SharePoint and OneDrive for business? I've been scratching my head for a few days trying to figure it out, but I'm having no luck.

What I need to do is create a report of any users in our Office 365 tenant that have files in their "Shared with Everyone" folder.

If anyone could even point me in the right direction, I'd certainly appreciate it. I'm a fair hand with PowerShell, but that isn't even helping much.

Thank you!

Comment: so you want all the users in oneDrive who have files in their "Shared with Everyone" folder? I am not sure about the rolde of SharePoint here. Kindly explain

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was under the impression that all OneDrive administration is handled through SharePoint, but I will admit I may be completely wrong.

Comment: OneDrive for Business is based on Sharepoint - the "Shared with Everyone" folder is simply a folder within the default document library in a users mysite

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Powershell you could try using the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` cmdlets, specifically:

> $web = Get-SPWeb http://{tenant's my site host}/personal/{user}
>   if ($web.GetFolder("Documents/Shared with Everyone").ItemCount -gt 0) { Write-Host "this user is using 'Shared With Everyone'" }

You'd of course have to have knowledge of all valid values of {user}, which you could grab using [this example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn911464.aspx).